# no such table: quotes (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR) : Android P

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have one quotes application in which I am using SqlLite Database for store quotes. When User Open Application, its copy data from Assets to database. Its working fine in all version but in Android P its crashing on application start.

its giving me error like

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: quotes (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(qu_text) AS count FROM quotes
```

I am sure that database does not getting copied, so there no table error coming but its only for Android P. Other version is working fine.

My DBHandler.java is like below

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "xxx";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    DBHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, constant.DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
    }
    void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            Log.e("database","exist");
        } else {

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }


    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

and class DAO.java has functions like below

```
private void open() throws SQLException {
    if(database!=null&&database.isOpen())return;
    database = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();

}


private void closeDAO(){
    synchronized (lockObj){
        if(dbHandler!=null)dbHandler.close();
        dbHandler=null;
        database=null;
    }
}



public static void dispose(){

    if(dBObject!=null){
        dBObject.closeDAO();
    }
    dBObject=null;
}
```

I have tried to close database connection like below before copy database as one of user have told in answer but still same errors coming .

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        db.close();

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

Let me know if someone can help to solve the puzzle. Thanks

Comment: May b there is PATH issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is intended behaviour in Android P. You can read details here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80268903

To fix the issue the app must make sure there are no open connections to the database before copying files.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can You please mention what changes I need to do in my case? Thanks

Comment: I have tried as per Your answer, I have edited my question with it. Its not working. Thanks

Comment: @Mira could you explain how you solved that issue? In your code, where have you close connections?